# C#: How to make sure the class finished the work, without relying on dependents?

Tags: c#, idisposable, finalizer

I have a class that collects a string. There is a method Commit, that writes the string to a target file.

If a string is collected, but the commit is never invoked, I want to report an error into a log file.

`IDisposable` will not solve the problem, because dependents will forget to invoke it.
I implemented a finalizer, but got compiler error:

> The class has a finalizer implemented in it.
>   Consider deriving from IDisposable, CriticalFinalizerObject or SafeHandle, instead.

I cannot change compiler settings in my company. And, the suggested options seem to be over-complicated. Any ideas how I implement validation for Commit?

Comment: what is the reason that causes Commit to not execute?

Comment: Can't you just let the method Commit return a boolean value; true if the commit is executed? Some code in your question might help, by the way.

Comment: You can do this by using a variable or return type.

Comment: `IDisposable` is about the best thing you'll find that's built in. Yes, it is *possible* for someone to ignore it's disposable-ness, but plenty of tooling will issue some form of warning about that sort of state.

Comment: @PolinaC, please could You specify how/what You do with the string? You are trying to collect, however You are not collecting it (so Execute is not called). Why this happens? Could You share some code sample?

Comment: Why don't you have the string collection and the writing to a file in the same action. i.e. if collecting a string and not saving it will cause an error, then they basically are part of the same task hence should be in the same action/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Question, it sounds to me something like this:

**Disclaimer, this is just poorly written code in Notepad, not tested.**

```
class CollectAndCommit : IDisposable
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool> collectedStrings { get; set; }

    public CollectAndCommit()
    {
        collectedStrings = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }

    public void Collect(string collectedString)
    {
        collectedStrings.Add(collectedString, false);
    }

    public void CommitAllUncommitedStrings()
    {
        foreach (var uncommitedString in collectedStrings.Where(c => c.Value == false))
        {
            collectedStrings[uncommitedString.Key] = Commit(uncommitedString.Key);
        }
    }

    public bool HasUncommitedStrings()
    {
        return collectedStrings.Count(c => c.Value == false) > 0;
    }

    private bool Commit(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(str);
            }   
            return true;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (HasUncommitedStrings())
        {
            throw new Exception("Uncommited Strings!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I have a class that collects a string. There is a method Commit, that
>   writes the string to a target file.

As far as I understand the problem, You are stucked with too long string reading, w/o calling Commit(string s) - there might be many reasons, like small memory (so during Load not whole string fits in memory) or You are reading from some stream which is continuous, ...

Now it depends where the program fails

Does it throw Exception? > **Use try-catch / re-throw error.**

Does it read without stopping? > **Give it time limit for reading, once overrun, throw error or just return with what You have & commit that.**

```
public class MyClass
{

    StringBuilder SB;

    public string ObtainString()
    {
        // This is executed, but takes lot of time/times out
        // Possible solution below

        SB = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        bool isRead = false;

        while(DateTime.Now.Add(20) > dt) && !isRead)
        {
            string helpVar = ReadPartOfFileOrBuffer();
            SB.Append(helpVar);

            isRead = checkIfFileOrBufferIsRead();
        };

        if(!isRead) throw new Exception("Read timed out");

        return SB.ToString();
    }

    public voic Commit(string s)
    {
        //This is not being executed!
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        string result = ObtainString();
        Commit(result);
    }
```